# Can't merge vertices or create faces with edges

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

I am trying to connect a bunch of duplicated and slightly modified shapes together, but merging or create face between lines does nothing. Any suggestions? [image]

Comment: Try the knife tool (K). Click to select the cut points and press Enter to finalize the cut.

Comment: I'd try to join the objects (in object mode) first, and then go to the edit mode to connect the verts.

Answer (score 1):

You have to join the meshes together first. Select an object, and then shift select all the other objects you want joined, and right click and press Join.

If you encounter another circumstance like this and they are joined, do what Christopher said and use the Knife tool.