# Having isssues with the merge tool

Tags: vertices

I´m trying to merge but when I tap "At last" or when I use the "L" key it doesn´t merge my vertices.

[image]

I need to join these two vertices however I can cause when I tap the "merge At last button" I doesn´t work at all.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, JuanJo .. We have absolutely no information to go on, here. Please illustrate with a screen-grab showing the topology, and your selection

Comment: Hi!....I just fix it! thank you for your attention!, It appears that you need to join the two objects before using merge tool so you can merge the vertices.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the edit. Your pictures appear to show 2 active (white) vertices. The only way I can reproduce this is if the vertices are on separate objects.. which would explain why you can't merge them. The objects would have to be joined first, (Ctrl J). If this is acceptable, this question may be closed as a duplicate of , for example, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/211824/cant-merge-vertices-or-create-faces-with-edges .  Nothing personal :) Let us know here if that's a fix